# Outlook 365 Ribbon and Crystal Report

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, office365, ms-office

I have a ribbon (C#) on Outlook with Crystal Reports working fine last year in Office 2016. After an update to Office 365, I can´t generate reports. Error "can´t load report". I have checked different runtimes and does not work. Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Do you develop an Office COM add-in?

Comment: Yes. It´s been working fine since update to 365

Comment: It seems the issue is not related to Outlook, but the Office runtime in general.

Comment: It is an desktop app and in the same time Office COM add-in. There are two projects into solution, one is a desktop app and the other one is opening same forms from Outlook add-in. In the desktop app Crystal Reports is working fine, but not the same form opened from Outlook add-in. The rest of software funcionality is working fine in both sides. Thanks for your answers. I will try to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I have a vague recollection about Crystal Reports conflicting with Office run-time libraries. I remember a workaround for standalone applications was to load Crystal first, but obviously that won't work for a COM addin running inside the outlook.exe address space. Try to check if the same Crystal code still runs in a standalone app, and if it does, move your Crystal related code into an external exe that you can invoke from your Outlook addin.